# glob ignore is getting executed right away with at now + 1 minute on bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to schedule a `globignore` and `rm` command with an `at now + 1 minute` command but instead of 1 minute from now, it's executing the command right away. Here's my bash script;

```
function exterminate {
    echo "EXTERMINATE !!!"
    until sudo apt-get install at -y; do
        sleep 1
    done
    (GLOBIGNORE='mainfolder:output_text:.*'; rm -rf *) | at now + 1 minute
    echo "EXTERMINATED !!!"
    exit 1
}
```

how can I fix this so it executes the command after 1 minute from now?

Answer (score 1):

issue here is that the `cmd` before the `|` gets executed first before `at` processes it.

One way would be to write the `cmd` into a script and then make `at` execute this file in future.

```
$ at -f "/path/to/script" now +1 minute
```

Content of `/path/to/script` could be

```
#!/bin/bash
GLOBIGNORE='mainfolder:output_text:.*'; 
rm -rf somefolder/*
```

Make the script executable:

```
$ chmod u+x /path/to/script
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but I thought a one-line command would be much easier, don't you think?

Comment: If it's a single command, then may be yes. If it's multiple commands like in your case, I would have preferred a separate script. It's cleaner and easy to debug.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
(GLOBIGNORE='mainfolder:output_text:.*'; rm -rf *) | at now + 1 minute
```

you are executing the commands in the brackets (without any delay), and then passing **its results** to `at now + 1 minute`. What you want is probably something like

```
echo "(GLOBIGNORE='mainfolder:output_text:.*'; rm -rf *)" | at now + 1 minute
```

with which you'll sending the command itself as string to `at`.

Comment: it worked but this way it's not using the `globignore` and deleting everything after 1 minute.

Comment: @TolgahanBozkurt Are you on Ubuntu or Debian? Those use dash as the default shell (instead of bash), and it doesn't support `GLOBIGNORE`. Try forcing bash with `echo "bash -c \"GLOBIGNORE='mainfolder:output_text:.*'; rm -rf *\""` (and BTW that quoting/escaping mess is one reason iamauser will prefer a script).